# Use Traefik to apply basic auth to all containers except one

Tags: docker-swarm, traefik

What's the best way to require basic auth for all containers except a select few?

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45301684/how-to-use-whitelisting-per-container) that's still waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that, you need to add basic auth on each frontend.

https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/#on-containers

Answer (score 1):

Add a basic auth label to your traefik container via labels

```
labels:
  # Basic Auth middleware
  - traefik.http.middlewares.YOUR_AUTH_MIDDLEWARE_NAME.basicauth.users=${TRAEFIK_BASICAUTH_USERS}
```

Then, in your other containers you can add the same middleware via label:

```
labels:
  - traefik.enable=true
  - traefik.port=80
  - traefik.http.routers.YOUR_ROUTER_NAME.rule=Host(`subdomain.domain.com`)
  - traefik.http.routers.YOUR_ROUTER_NAME.entryPoints=websecure
  - traefik.http.routers.YOUR_ROUTER_NAME.middlewares=YOUR_AUTH_MIDDLEWARE_NAME # <- this enables basic auth, using the same users
```

For the container that shouldn't have basic auth, just remove that last label

Answer (score 0):

You could add auth to just to some containers using traefik labels on it. For example:

Two containers on a stack, one has this label:

`"traefik.frontend.auth.basic=user:$$apr1$$9Cv/OMGj$$ZomWQzuQbL.3TRCS81A1g/"`

The other doesn't have it. Accessing the first container would require auth on the user `user`. The other one would be open.

Reference: https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/#on-containers